# Consulta anidada

Tags: sql, subconsultas, transact-sql

Quiero insertar el resultado de la Consulta:

```
SELECT * 
from c_albventemp 
JOIN (
    select numero, letra 
    from d_albventemp 
    where len(definicion)>60
) AS detall ON c_albventemp.NUMERO = detall.NUMERO AND c_albventemp.LETRA = detall.letra
```

En una tabla con la misma estructura que **c_albentemp** de la siguiente manera:

```
insert into c_albven 
SELECT * 
from c_albventemp 
JOIN (
    select numero, letra 
    from d_albventemp 
    where len(definicion)>60
) AS detall ON c_albventemp.NUMERO = detall.NUMERO AND c_albventemp.LETRA = detall.letra
```

Pero me da un error, veo que el error es porqué me devuelve también los campos **número** y **letra** de la subconsulta.
¿Como puedo obviar esos campos sin que alteren la consulta?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque no es una práctica muy recomendable (utilizar los *), tu solución es simple. En el select cambias el `*` por `c_albventemp.*`

```
insert into c_albven 
SELECT c_albventemp.* 
from c_albventemp 
JOIN (
    select numero, letra 
    from d_albventemp 
    where len(definicion)>60
) AS detall ON c_albventemp.NUMERO = detall.NUMERO AND c_albventemp.LETRA = detall.letra
```

Comment: Como efectivamente dice Roger, cuando haces *, también incluyes los campos del JOIN (numero y letra). Si aplicas la solución de Roger, indicas que solo quieres centrarte en la tabla c_albventemp, excluyendo los campos del JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

A falta de tener la estructura de tus tablas para poder realizar pruebas, dejo por aquí esta solución sin utilizar joins, haciendo 2 subconsultas.

```
INSERT INTO c_albven
SELECT * FROM c_albventemp 
WHERE c_albventemp.NUMERO in (select NUMERO from d_albventemp where len(definicion)>60) AND 
    c_albventemp.LETRA in (select LETRA from d_albventemp where len(definicion)>60)
```